# How can I make a bar plot using many names in x axis in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have a simple question.
I need make a bar plot for c using a limit (0.4 to 1.0) and I need all the names in the x-axis(1-
100).

```
  name=seq(1:1000)
  c=runif(1000,0.4,1.0)
  c=round(c,2)
```

How can I do that?
     I tried just

```
     barplot(c,names.arg=name, ylim=c(0.4,1.0))
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you need 100 x axis labels, or 1000? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Sorry I need 1000 labels in x axis and y axis 0.4 to 1.0.

Comment: Then read my comment below. There is no way you will fit 1000 labels there and have them be readable. Unless you're planning on making your graph like 10k pixels wide, or wider...?

Comment: The bars overlapping the labels is a separate problem. Cutting off the y axis like that is considered a Very Bad Thing, so you'll have to do some manual stuff. Subtract 0.4 from your data, omit the `ylim` part, and then relabel the y axis to run from 0.4 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

For an example of how to make the x axis labels at least visible, while restricting the y axis, consider doing something like this:

```
barplot(c - 0.4,names.arg=name,axes = FALSE)
axis(side = 2,at = seq(0,0.6,by = 0.2),labels = as.character(seq(0.4,1.0,by = 0.2)))
```

But note that:

1. You shouldn't name variables `c`, it's confusing.
2. You really aren't going to fit 1000 labels under there. You figure at at least 15-20 pixels for each number, even if turned vertically, times 1000 and you've got yourself a very large image.

You should rethink whether a visualization like this is really meaningful.

Comment: @Cris I honestly don't know how much more clearly I can explain this. You need to think very carefully about how many pixels your computer screen has, and given how many pixels you'd need to display a single number, how large a screen you'd need in this case. Once again, what you're trying to do is _fundamentally a bad idea_ and you should rethink your entire approach.